# (VB.NET) See what files a process is accessing

Tags: windows, vb.net, file, operating-system

How do Antiviruses such as AVG detect files accessed by specific programs such as explorer.exe?

How can this monitoring of which process accessing which files be done in VB.NET?

Comment: My bet is on file system drivers, and I doubt that VB.Net would be fast enough to implement them (even if possible at all).

Comment: common this was pure programming question !! it shouldn't be on hold !!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) springs to mind.

[With further API calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531800/how-does-a-windows-antivirus-hook-into-the-file-access-process), you could theoretically write your own AV tool and hook into all file access. But [this probably only deasible with C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541401/is-it-possible-to-trace-file-operations-with-net).

You could turn on [File System Auditing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772661%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and use VB.Net to parse the torrent of events in the Audit Event Log.

Comment: Doesn't file system watcher only monitor files created/renamed, not files accessed by a specific process.

Comment: @user2514562, that is true. If you need to know what changed the file FSW is not enough.